# How to debug a g++ segmentation fault using gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I got a segfault when running my program. Then I googled my question and tried to follow steps from https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/bugs/segfault.html.

I did not configure GCC with `--enable-checking` then my first question is -

1) is it necessary to configure it and compile with `-v -da -Q` ?

But I always do compile with flags such as `-g -o0`. After running the program in GDB with arguments I get this:

[image: gdb_screenshot]

2) I can not print variables after segfault, is it okay ?

3) How to figure out the line of my source code where segfault happens ?

Comment: That information you're looking for appears to be clearly listed in frame #1 of the shown backtrace.

Comment: I apologize for inattention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then I googled my question and tried to follow steps from > https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/bugs/segfault.html.

These are the steps for GCC *developers* to follow when GCC itself crashes while compiling your program.

These are *not* the steps you should follow when debugging a crash in the program itself.

Instead, [read this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

> How to figure out the line of my source code where segfault happens ?

GDB *told* you the line: it's `common/search.cpp` line 172.